# Django quering objects with timestamp delta

Tags: python, django, timestamp

Say I have a model:

```
Mymodel(models.Model):
    endtimestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

I need a query to get all Mymodel objects with endstimestamp between today's midnight and yesterday midnight.

what have I tried:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
todays_midnigh = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
    today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.0')
)
yesterday_midnight = todays_midnight - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
objs = Mymodel.objects.filter(endtimestamp__range(
    yesterday_midnight, todays_midnight)
)
```

But this line `todays_midnigh = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.0'))` does not work, and I know there must be a much pythonic and clear way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assumming this `from datetime import datetime as dt`, do that:

```
today = dt.today()
todays_midnigh = dt.combine(today,dt.max.time())
```

or

```
todays_midnigh = dt.combine(today,dt.min.time())
```

as appropriate